# Axis2 webservice created via JAVA is not accepting null values

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-axis, axis

I am using Axis2 service Archiver to create web service through my java code and testing it with SOAP UI.When i am passing the null value in any of the attribute it is showing me "Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method" error.i am passing multiple parameters(attributes) in the argument while calling the method in my JAVA code.I am checking the null values in my java code as well.Is it like SOAP UI does not find any operation in my java file with less number of arguments ? If yes then should i write multiple methods and override the method every time ?

below is operation of my WS :

```
enter code here

***<xs:complexType name="AssetDetails">
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GRNDate" nillable="true" type="xs:date" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="GRNNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PODate" nillable="true" type="xs:date" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="POLine" type="xs:int" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PONumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PRLine" type="xs:int" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="PRNumber" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SAPAssetCode" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="message" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="status" nillable="true" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>***
```

and correspondingly JAVA method call is :

```
public AssetDetails SetAssetInfo(Date GRNDate,String GRNNumber,Date PODate,int POLine,String PONumber,int PRLine,String PRNumber,String SAPAssercode,String status )
```

so here is the call for 9 arguments but if i put null in SOAP UI for any of the attribute it will search for the method which has 8 arguments.

Please help !!
Thanks !!

Comment: Please check the web service logs to know what happens

Comment: I checked the logs.When i am missing any of the attribute in SOAP UI request,it is not able to find same number of arguments operation (method) in JAVA. I am confuse that i should write methods with each number of arguments.